# How to programatically modify systemd unit files?

Tags: shell, shell-script, systemd

I'd like to edit a systemd's unit file from a shell script. I want to change the unit's only *ExecStart* line. Using `systemctl edit` looks smart to me, but the command needs an editor set as `SYSTEMD_EDITOR` environment variable. Is there any `SYSTEMD_EDITOR` alternative which would be used like `echo 'ExecStart=foo' | SYSTEMD_EDITOR=SOMETHING systemctl edit bar`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't *need to* go through the command – you can directly create the same files for systemd's "override" mechanism that it uses:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/foobar.service.d

cat > /etc/systemd/system/foobar.service.d/10-my-edits.conf <<EOF
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=foo
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
```

The override or "drop-in" mechanism is documented in [systemd.unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

Comment: I think after `systemctl daemon-reload`, the service has to be restarted (e.g. via `systemctl restart foobar.service`) in order for the newly added drop-in ("override") to take effect.

Comment: In this answer's current version, is there a particular reason for first having `ExecStart=`, then `ExecStart=foo`?

Comment: That's the method for removing all current values from a multi-valued parameter, before adding a new one.

Comment: thanks, and good to know! It seems to me that this "property clear/reset" feature is not explicitly documented in the systemd documentation. Only on https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Examples did I find a hint for it: ... "*Note that for drop-in files, if one wants to remove entries from a setting that is parsed as a list (and is not a dependency), such as AssertPathExists= (or e.g. ExecStart= in service units), one needs to first clear the list before re-adding all entries except the one that is to be removed.*"

Comment: Not sure where else it should be if not in the unit format docs?